# Dynamics CRM QueryExpression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, query-expressions

I have this query that populates a joborder with the notes (2 different types) that comes from the account on the job order. The problem that I'm having is that it works on most of the job orders but there are some that I'm noticing that the notes are not populating to. It seems to me that the account entity and internal notes are a one to many relationship, however I must be going about this all wrong. I also have below the FetchXML that I modeled my query from.

```csh
  private  void PopulateInternalNotes()
  {
      EntityReference accountId = _Entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("hc_account");
      EntityReference buisnessId = _Entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("hc_businessunit");

      if(accountId == null || buisnessId ==null)
      {
          return;
      }
      _tracer.Trace("buisness unit: " + buisnessId);
     //to get internal description
      QueryExpression exp = new QueryExpression("hc_internalnote");

      exp.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_internalnotetype", ConditionOperator.Equal, 948050000); // internal description option
      exp.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_account", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountId.Id);// matches account on joborder
      exp.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_businessunit", ConditionOperator.Equal, buisnessId.Id);//matches buisnessunit on joborder

      exp.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("hc_note");
      EntityCollection results = _service.RetrieveMultiple(exp);
      if (results.Entities.Count == 1)
      {
          foreach (Entity r in results.Entities)
          {
              _tracer.Trace("one  internal desc found");
              _Entity["hc_internaldescription"] = r.GetAttributeValue<string>("hc_note");

          }
      }
      else
      {
          _tracer.Trace("no internal desc found");
      }

      //to get submission process note
      QueryExpression sub = new QueryExpression("hc_internalnote");


      sub.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_internalnotetype", ConditionOperator.Equal, 948050002); // submission process  option
      sub.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_account", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountId.Id);// matches account on joborder
      sub.Criteria.AddCondition("hc_businessunit", ConditionOperator.Equal, buisnessId.Id);//matches buisnessunit on joborder

      sub.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("hc_note");
      EntityCollection Subresults = _service.RetrieveMultiple(sub);
      if (Subresults.Entities.Count == 1)
      {
          foreach (Entity s in Subresults.Entities)
          {
              _tracer.Trace("one submission desc found");
              _Entity["hc_submissionprocessnotes"] = s.GetAttributeValue<string>("hc_note");

          }
      }
      else
      {
          _tracer.Trace("more than one submission note found");
      }

  }
```

FetchXML below

```xml
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
  <entity name="hc_internalnote">
    <attribute name="createdon"/>
    <attribute name="statecode"/>
    <attribute name="ownerid"/>
    <attribute name="hc_note"/>
    <attribute name="modifiedon"/>
    <attribute name="modifiedby"/>
    <attribute name="hc_internalnotetype"/>
    <attribute name="createdby"/>
    <attribute name="hc_contract"/>
    <attribute name="hc_businessunit"/>
    <attribute name="hc_account"/>
    <attribute name="hc_internalnoteid"/>
    <order descending="false" attribute="createdon"/>
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="hc_account" value="{B1F13E37-2D34-E411-9518-005056010301}" uitype="account" uiname="Community Memorial Hospital (050394)" operator="eq"/>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: so notes are not coming in resultset for some records, though its available in system? both fetchxml & QE?

Comment: seems to be working .the problem was old records were migrated and our plugins were off hence the not populating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comments:*

Seems to be working. The problem was with old records which were migrated during our plugins were off, hence they are not populating.